# SVG: This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it

Tags: python, svg

I am trying to get some project data from GitHub and visualize it, but my program appears to have a bug. When I open the SVG file, I get: `This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it`. The document tree is shown below. Is there a problem with the program? Thank you.

```
import requests
import pygal
from pygal.style import LightColorizedStyle as Lcs,  LightenStyle as Ls

URL = 'https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=language:python&sort=stars'
r = requests.get(URL)
print("Status code:", r.status_code)

response_dict = r.json()
print("Total repositories:", response_dict['total_count'])
repo_dicts = response_dict['items']
names, plot_dicts = [], []
for repo_dict in repo_dicts:
    names.append(repo_dict['name'])

    plot_dict = {
        'value': repo_dict['stargazers_count'],
        'label': repo_dict['description'],
    }
    plot_dicts.append(plot_dict)
my_style = Ls('#333666', base_style=Lcs)
chart = pygal.Bar(style=my_style, x_label_rotation=45, show_legend=False)
chart.title = 'Most-Starred Python Projects on GitHub'
chart.x_labels = names

chart.add('', plot_dicts)
chart.render_to_file('python_repos.svg')
```

Comment: looks like render_to_file is not putting a namespace in the svg file it outputs.

Comment: How should i deal with it?@alxwrd

Comment: download the source code and fix it yourself or raise a bug on the project's bugtracker and wait for it to be fixed.